# Appending a tally of subjects to a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a list of subjects:

```
myDat = list(Subject = c(10234, 10234, 10234, 10234, 10242, 10242, 10242, 10242, 10253, 10253, 10253, 10268, 10268, 10268, 10268))
```

and I would like to add a count (`DayNo`) which restarts with every change in subject to the dataframe to look like:

[image: Subjects with count]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `ave` variant:

```
df <- as.data.frame(myDat)
df$Day <- ave(df$Subject, df$Subject, FUN=seq_along)
```

Produces:

```
   Subject Day
1    10234   1
2    10234   2
3    10234   3
4    10234   4
5    10242   1
6    10242   2
7    10242   3
8    10242   4
9    10253   1
10   10253   2
11   10253   3
12   10268   1
13   10268   2
14   10268   3
15   10268   4
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `rle` to get the run lengths and use `sequence` to create sequences of corresponding length.

```
myDat <- as.data.frame(myDat)
myDat$DayNo <- sequence(rle(myDat$Subject)$lengths)
#    Subject DayNo
# 1    10234     1
# 2    10234     2
# 3    10234     3
# 4    10234     4
# 5    10242     1
# 6    10242     2
# 7    10242     3
# 8    10242     4
# 9    10253     1
# 10   10253     2
# 11   10253     3
# 12   10268     1
# 13   10268     2
# 14   10268     3
# 15   10268     4
```